# azure key vault firewall settings using api

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-management-api

Is it possible to restrict an azure key vault's firewall to specific Ip's using c# code, the last thread i could find on the Microsoft forum was dated on august 2017 saying it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes, currently it's not possible. There is already an [open user feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170024-additional-services/suggestions/14649549-restrict-access-to-list-of-ip-addresses) on this. Please do vote on that.

Comment: it was dated on 2016, didn't find any latest updates as i mentioned earlier. is it still unavailable??

Comment: @user6260854 yes if it's available means, you will see the feedback has completed (State). But the current state is still open,which means it's unavailable as of now